# Prevent navigation and get the target link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my website faster by changing the content code via Ajax instead of navigating and reloading the page. But I also care about non-Javascript users so I want to use normal links instead of onclick event. And I want to prevent navigating and getting the target href link to change the content.

Is there a way to achieve that with Javascript/jQuery? Apparently jQuery supports `event.preventDefault();` but I don't think it gives you an ability to get target link from that event...

Comment: You should not copy code from the answer into the question. All that does it make it harder for future visitors to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in JavaScript (without using jQuery)

To catch all the clicks in document you can use

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const href = e.target.href
})
```

also you should add additional check that clicked element is exactly a link with href:

```
e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a'
```

So an example of working code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    e.preventDefault()
    const href = e.target.href
  } 
})
```

With this function you will be able to catch all the clicks, check, if user clicked on `a` and get `href` attribute with just plain javascript. http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

**Update**
Based on **@AVAVT** comment if you need to handle case with something nested inside `a`, like

```
<a href="https://google.com"> 
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"> 
</a>
```

just use `e.target.closest('a')`

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('a')) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const href = e.target.closest('a').href
  } 
})
```

because `target` property will lead to exactly clicked item (in this case `img`) we need to check is it a child of `a` and then prevent default behavior.

Note:

> jQuery solution is simple, so it's preferred, if you already have jQuery on the page.

Otherwise you can go without it with plain javascript.

Comment: This solution still contain flaw. In cases where there's nested element inside the `a`, for example an `<img>`, `e.target` will be the `img` element instead of the `a`. See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/58zxju0m/. After you solve that part it would be a complete solution. Personally though since the OP mentioned s/he's already using jQuery I think my solution's a lot shorter and easier to understand. This is one of the cases where I believe jQuery still triumph over pure js because it's cleaner to read.

Comment: Why bother with finding element, when you can use **e.currentTarget**, which is reference to element that the event is registered on, rather than which triggered event, in this case it will always be the desired "a" tag.

Comment: @Meyhem if you meant code snippets from my answer, you'd notice `currentTarget` is `body`, so it doesn't really help to find `a` . Do you mean that it's better to have many even listeners  - one per `a` instead?

Comment: @uladzimir You're right, that would work only if the click event would be registered directly on all anchors. I have missed that.

Answer (score 3):

I think jQuery's [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) can help you:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  doSomethingWith($(this).attr('href'));
});
```